# Union all for two tables then nested with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

t1

```
DocNo                         Date            Description
Doc-12345-67890               15Jan19         QC-Passed            

t2
DocNo                         Date            Description
Doc-09876-21347               16Jan19         QC-Passed      

t3
DocNo                         Date            Description
12345                         15Jan19         QC-Passed                   
09876                         16Jan19         QC-Passed  

Select *
from
(
select left(right(docno,len(docno)-3),5) as DocNo,Date,Description 
from t1
union all
select *
from t2) as RC    
inner join    
t3    
on
rc.docno=t3.docno
```

It does not work, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? Are you getting the wrong results? An error?

Comment: Going to guess that the OP is getting an error that the data types aren't the same in the `UNION ALL` The top query has a `varchar(5)`,where as the bottom has a `varchar(15)` at least. But, that's a guess, as we don't have details of the error or the unexpected behaviour/results.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Show your error or the result you are getting and show us what you want instead. Explain the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your data is such that the t3 table is the driver with it's docno being the primary to the first five characters of t1 and t2 after the 'Doc-' text.  The tsql below grabs the 't1' and 't2' DocNo by using SubString:

Query:

```
Select *
from
(
select SubString(DocNo,5,5) as DocNo,dt,Description 
from #tbl1
union all
select SubString(DocNo,5,5) as DocNo,dt,Description
from #tbl2) as RC    
inner join    
#tbl3    
on
rc.docno=#tbl3.docno
```

Result:

```
DocNo   dt      Description DocNo   dt      Description
12345   15Jan19 QC-Passed   12345   15Jan19 QC-Passed
09876   16Jan19 QC-Passed   09876   16Jan19 QC-Passed
```

Comment: This works: (Thank you)   select *
from ((select DocNo, Date, Description 
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select DocNo, Date, Description
       from t2
      )
     ) RC inner join    
     t3    
     on left(right(rc.docno, len(rc.docno) - 3), 5) = t3.docno;
Or:

select *
from ((select left(right(rc.docno, len(rc.docno) - 3), 5) as DocNo, Date, Description 
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select left(right(rc.docno, len(rc.docno) - 3), 5) as DocNo, Date, Description
       from t2
      )
     ) RC inner join    
     t3    
     on rc.docno = t3.docno;

Comment: @MitchelAraw Then mark this suggestion as the answer. Because that is how SO is designed to work. People who have questions search to find answers. They can't find answers if you don't mark them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select *
from ((select DocNo, Date, Description 
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select DocNo, Date, Description
       from t2
      )
     ) RC inner join    
     t3    
     on left(right(rc.docno, len(rc.docno) - 3), 5) = t3.docno;
```

Or:

```
select *
from ((select left(right(rc.docno, len(rc.docno) - 3), 5) as DocNo, Date, Description 
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select left(right(rc.docno, len(rc.docno) - 3), 5) as DocNo, Date, Description
       from t2
      )
     ) RC inner join    
     t3    
     on rc.docno = t3.docno;
```

In other words, the expression in the first `select` of the `union all` doesn't "carry over" into the second `select`.

Comment: I think this is what OP wants - but needs "len(rc.docno) - 4)"

Comment: @MitchelAraw . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?